# How do I programatically get the templated response string from an intent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sirishortcuts

I've set up a bunch of intents in my intent definition file.  Each of them has a response template for each response status.

When I perform an interaction for one of those intents, my app delegate's [`-application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623072-application?language=objc) method is called, and the interaction and its intent are available in the `continueUserActivity` argument.  I'd like to show the message that I set up in the response template to the user.  I can get the parameters from the intent response, but not the templated response string, nor even the just template.

How do I programatically get the templated response string from the intent?